# Custom serialization of class fails

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a class where I store information about files (path etc.). I only serialize the class, when I want to send the files and other information to another Person.

There I have a problem with files bigger than 1019 bytes: they are not stored the right way.

I was able to recreate the issue with this example class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializableImage implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2079629440538093893L;
    private String path;
    private byte[] data;


    public SerializableImage()
    {}

    public SerializableImage(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        int imageSize = ois.readInt();
        data = new byte[imageSize];
        ois.read(data);
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
        int imageSize;
        File file = new File(path);
        imageSize = (int) file.length();
        oos.writeInt(imageSize);
        InputStream is = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[imageSize];

        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            is.read(buffer);
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }

        oos.write(buffer);
    }
}
```

Attribute imageSize is written the right way, and also the bytes are read to the buffer the right way (compared it to "file clone" with just a FileInputStream and a FileOutputStream, so I know the information written to the buffer byte array is correct).

The Question now is:
Is there a problem with the oos.write(buffer)?
Or is the problem in the ois.read(data)?
imageSize is written/read the right way.

I always got wrong values in the data byte array starting at index 1020.

I "tested" this class with this code:

```
    SerializableImage sourceImage = new SerializableImage("C:\\\\source.jpg");
    File serializableData = new File("C:\\\\data.data");
    File targetImage = new File("C:\\\\target.jpg");

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serializableData));
    oos.writeObject(sourceImage);

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(serializableData));

    sourceImage = (SerializableImage) ois.readObject();
    FileOutputStream imageOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetImage);

    byte[] data = sourceImage.getData();
    imageOutputStream.write(data);
    imageOutputStream.flush();
    ois.close();
    oos.close();
    imageOutputStream.close();
```

Is there something obvious I did not recognise? I do not get an error message or something. The only way to notice it is that to target image is invalid.

Comment: It seems odd to me that you read a file in  `writeObject`, especially given that you have a no-arg constructor and `path` could be `null`. You also don't check the return value from `read`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html says "Any object, including Strings and arrays, is written with writeObject."  -- have you tried  readObject` and `writeObject` instead of the simple `read` and `write` methods? And why even have your own `readObject` and `writeObject` methods?

Comment: It's just a class to show how I get the problem - everything regarding null etc. is not importamt at this point because its only a example to reproduce it. The same is for not checking read return value. For sure I do it in my "real" class. I will check the writeObject point as soon as I'm on my machine again.

Comment: You should close the oos stream before trying to read it, it is not guaranteed to be flushed to disk already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert stated in the comments under the question writeObject should always be used when working with a ObjectOutputStream. Also write(byte[] data) would acceppt a byte array. The same is true for reading with readObject and read.